# How to retry starting Apache Camel RabbitMQ consumer router if the RabbitMQ server is temporarily unavailable

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, spring-rabbit

I have a simple Apache Camel route

```
     from("spring-rabbitmq:myExchange?routingKey=foo&bridgeErrorHandler=true")
        .log("From RabbitMQ: ${body}");
```

The sample project is [here](https://github.com/jirmed/camel-rabbitmq-exceptions).

If the RabbitMQ server is up and running when I start the route, everything works fine. The problem is if the RabbitMQ is not available on the route start the route startup terminates with org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException.

Is there any way how to handle the exception and retry several times after some delay starting the route again?

I tried to add `onException` but that seems to work for producer ("to" endpoint) only.

I have also found Apace Camel `RoutePolicy.` It's method onInit is triggered before the route crashes so it might be used somehow to retry the route startup but the documentation is not very exhausting and I have not found any example either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes see supervising route controller
https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-controller.html

Also you may look at the rabbitmq connection factory (spring rabbitmq stuff) as it may have some kind of retry built-in as well, you can configure.

Answer (score 0):

With the usage of Supervising controler (thanks to @ClausIbsen) i solved the issue by adding following lines to my `application.properties` file

```
# Set Supervising controller
camel.springboot.route-controller-supervise-enabled = true

# and you can configure more options
camel.springboot.routeControllerBackoffDelay = 5000    
camel.springboot.routeControllerBackoffMaxAttempts = 3
camel.springboot.routeControllerInitialDelay = 1000
camel.springboot.routeControllerThreadPoolSize = 2
```

The trick was to replace

```
camel.springboot.route-controller-enabled = true
```

as stated in the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-controller.html) with

```
camel.springboot.route-controller-supervise-enabled = true
```